# How do I create this rule in Magento, based on a particular product's quantity?

Tags: php, magento, magento-rules

I need to make a single rule in magento that fulfills following conditions.

There are 10 products from which 3 products should have the following rules apply.

1. On their initial price, if the user buys 1 product they will get $20 off.
2. If the user buys more than 1 combination of products from that 3, then they will get $25 off each product.

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I am slightly confused about how your rule works.  You have 10 products.  Is that information important to your rule?  Or will the rule only apply to those 3 products?  And what do you mean by "if the user buys more than 1 combination of products from that 3"?  Do you mean: *If the user has one of those three products in their basket, they get $20 off.  If they have 2 of those in their basket, they get 50$ off the total ($25 off each).  If they have 3, they get  $75 off the total ($25 off each).* - What if they have a quantity > 1 of those products.  Do they keep getting $25 off?

Comment: As in, could you word it this way?: `$20 off a single sale item, or $25 off each sale item, if you purchase two or more sale items`.  And, is there any limit to this?  Can you only get the discount once per item type?  What if you buy two of the same sale item type?

Answer (score 0):

Take these three products, and recreate them in a new attribute set. We'll call it promo.

I would simply create a rule in "Shopping Cart Price Rules" stating this:

**If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: Attribute Set  is  Promo**

Then discount the situation accordingly in the "Actions" Tab.

You can add another rule for three, four, five and so one within one rule.